# How to stop 2 path inside an svg from connecting with each other?

Tags: javascript, svg

So, I am making a program that allow the user draw a line. When the user finish drawing this line, I get an array of points, like `[[x, y], [x, y], ...]`.

Then I create a path string from this points using this function:

```
export const pointsToSVGPathString = (points) => points
    .map(({x, y}, idx) => idx ? `${x} ${y}`:`M ${x} ${y}`)
    .join(' ')
```

Once I get the string, I create a new path element like this:

```
export const createSvgFromPoints = (points, namespaceURI) => {
const path = document.createElementNS(namespaceURI, "path");
const stroke = pointsToSVGPathString(points)
path.setAttributeNS(null, 'd', stroke)
path.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "none");
path.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke", COLOR_WRITING.DRAWING_COLOR); 
path.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-width", 9);  
path.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-linecap", 'round');  
path.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-linejoin", 'round');  

return path
}
```

And then I get the target svg element by document get by id and append the retrieved path using `appendchild()`.

It works fine, except that, every time a new line is created and append to the svg, its start will be connected to the end of the previous line.

How can I prevent it from doing that?

Comment: Path elements are independent and won't automatically connect to each other. It seems like your point data might be different than you expect it to be, with the lines overlapping when you expect them to not. Try creating a working [mcve] with real data in a StackSnippet.

Comment: Thank to this part of your comment: "the lines overlapping when you expect them to not", I figured out that when I get the array of points after the user finish drawing the line, I need to clear it for the next line that the user draw, otherwise the coordinate data of the last line will be part of the next line.

Comment: If your path only consists of straight lines, then you might find it more efficient to use a `<polyline>` or `<polygon>` element instead.

Comment: Do you empty the array of points after you create the new path? If you don't you are using the points from the previous path together with the new points to create the new d attribute

Comment: I didn't, and that was the mistake. I fixed it tho.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use points from the previous path together with new points then you have to empty the array of points before you create the new path.